# Declaring a variable type from std::type_info

Tags: c++, c++-templates

Can I declare variable type just from `std::type_info`? I would like to do something like this:

```
void some_function(std::type_info type){
    type variable;
}
```

Is it possible to give it as the parameter to the function and initialize it in it?

Comment: No. What are you trying to do? You may get better answers if you identify a reasonable use case.

Comment: If you try you will know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a template:

```
template <typename T>
void some()
{
    T variable;
}

//usage:
some<int>();
```

As C++ is statically typed, it is impossible to determine vairable type in runtime, so all types should be known at compile time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this is incorrect C++ since the `type` in the function declaraition is a variable name, and the `type` in the function body is a type name. Those can not be interchanged.

(Note: I'm deducing this by pure logic and some knowledge of C++. Other users will most probably add some information about `std::type_info` itself.)